# Slow loading times on chrome only

Tags: php, performance, google-chrome

A website im working on "digiteksolutions.ie" is loading very slow on chrome but quick on all other browsers? I have tried multiple computers and all the same, its also slow in Incongito.

I have been told that upgrading the PHP in server might fix. Would anyone else have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question like: *What have you tried so far?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Ca you tell us more info about your environment? your server specs. php version. any other detail?

Comment: PHP is server side, are you sure you don't have any script running on client that may slow down chrome? You can also check the network tab of the chrome developer panel to see what's slow to download from the server. This also can be a chrome bug.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your replies. PHP version is 5.3.3. Hosted in AWS. Its a wordpress site so I have updated all plugins etc. It loads quick on chrome app on mobile but not desktop. I have deleted and re-installed chrome but same issues. Thanks